# In what python library is google.cloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I've used pip (and pip3) to install google-api-python-client, all over the place, but whenever I try to issue

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

I get an

> ImportError: No module named google.cloud" error.

`sys.path` contains the directory that pip reports google-api-python-client is installed in, although it's near the end of a long(ish) list of directories.

Edit:

I've also installed google-cloud.  The error occurs with both libraries installed.

Edit2:  the Location for both are:  "/home/swood/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages"

print(sys.path) returns:  ['/mnt/pasnas00/dbdata/snowflakedata/lib', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/swood/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: Can we see `pip3 show google-api-python-client | grep Location` and `print(sys.path)`. Replace `grep` with `findstr` if you are using windows.

Comment: i'd recommend using a `virtualenv` as well so you can be 100% sure of what is installed and where it comes any source of conflict between packages.

Answer (score 2):

That's because those are different libraries. You have installed the [Google API Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) and trying to import the [Google Cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) one. For an overview of the differences you can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

Install it with this instead:

```
pip install google-cloud
```

or with `pip3` for Python3. If you still want to use the other Client you'll need to import it and build the BigQuery service with something like this:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
...
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had installed google-cloud, too.  That error occurs with both installed.  I've edited the original question to reflect that.